# Getting wrong quality when using SeqIO convert from ab1 to fastq

Tags: python, biopython

im using SeqIO from Biopython package to convert ab1 files to fastq file and some of the files are getting wrong scores.
actually only one score ("!")

```
SeqIO.convert('filename'+'.ab1', "abi", 'filename'+".fastq", "fastq")
```

example of result:

> @filename
>   GAACNGNCGCTGCCTATACTGCAAGTCGAGCGGACAGTAAGGGAGCTTGCTCCCGGATGTTAGCGGCGGACGGGT
>   + !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

The conversion does not work in any programe so the problem seems to be in the files itself.

Comment: a regular ab1 file with quite good qualities , i cannot open it in a text editor so i cannot show anything

Comment: how do you know it's a regular ab1 file? how have you inspected it? Can you create a MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There  are regular ab1 files, I can inspect them in a sequence software called chromas.everything with those files work fine. And what is mcve?

Comment: i tried to use an online converter program  ant got the same.

Comment: biopython is probably not able to do that. Take a look here: https://github.com/gear-genomics/tracy

Comment: the problem is not the software witch work well on some files, but in the files that have some bug.

Comment: @YosDos I guess you need to share the files than. Can't guess the bug in the files if we don't have the files.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @YosDos Use a pastebin service, like pastebin.com. (PS. If you type @ myname I'll get a notification and I don't have to remember to come to this answer.)

Comment: @HielkeWalinga Thank you,  i am sharing the file via google drive:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/16QcXrByySk0m6skYtW2AFKq1Gv9mV1D1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @YosDos https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/1531 seems related